# Writing the mean-field Hamiltonian of the 1d Ising model including nearest and next-nearest neighbour interactions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, ising-model

for an exercise I have to consider the 1d Ising model with a Hamiltonian of the form

H = $-J_1 \sum_{i-1}^{N}S_{i}S_{i+1} - J_{2}\sum_{i=1}^{N}S_{i}S_{i+2}$.

We assume the system has periodic boundary conditions so $S_{N+1} = S_1$. Now you have to use a mean field approximation $S_i = \langle S \rangle + \delta S_i$ to show that we can write the Hamiltonian in the form

$H = A\langle S \rangle ^2 - B \langle S \rangle \sum_{i=1}^{N}S_i$.

Ive gotten to the point where I wrote it as

$H = N(J_1 + J_2)\langle S \rangle ^2 - \langle S \rangle \sum_{i=1}^{N}(J_1 + J_2)S_i + J_1 S_{i+1} + J_2 S_{i+2}$

but I dont know if Im on the right track or how I should continue. Any help with this exercise would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/75633) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/75633). You might want to consider posting at the [PhysicsForums](https://www.physicsforums.com/forums/homework-and-coursework-questions.152/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just use periodic boundary conditions: $S_{N+1}=S_1$ and $S_{N+2}=S_2$, in such a way $\sum_{i=1}^N S_{i+1} = \sum_{i=1}^N S_{i+2} = \sum_{i=1}^N S_i $, so $B=2(J_1+J_2)$.